# How to display Size (pips) of box.new (gaps) - Condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm working on improving a script that displays gaps. I'm stuck on labels, I'd like to not display the labels whose gaps have been filled. I have no idea how to exclude them, do you have an idea of condition line ?

The script displays the box gaps well but I can't find the line that would allow not to display the filled gaps labels

EDIT : I would like to display pips between bottom and top of the boxes

[Label Gap picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrIvg.jpg)

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © ArthurBuyStock

//@version=5
indicator("Gap", overlay = true)

b = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', bar_index, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)


string nintendo = input.string("Intuition", "Type", options = ["True", "Fix", "Intuition"])
var box[] bricks = array.new_box()
switch nintendo

    "True" => 
        if b != b[1]
            if open > high[1]
                array.unshift(bricks, box.new(bar_index - 1, open, bar_index, close[1], na, extend  = extend.right, bgcolor = color.green)) 
            else if open < low[1]
                array.unshift(bricks, box.new(bar_index - 1, close[1], bar_index, open, na, extend  = extend.right, bgcolor = color.red)) 
    "Fix" => 
        if b != b[1]
            if open > h
                array.unshift(bricks, box.new(bar_index - 1, open, bar_index, close[1], na, extend  = extend.right, bgcolor = na))
            else if open < l
                array.unshift(bricks, box.new(bar_index - 1, close[1], bar_index, open, na, extend  = extend.right, bgcolor = na))
    "Intuition" =>
        if open > high[1] 
            array.unshift(bricks, box.new(left= bar_index - 1, top= open, right= bar_index, bottom = high[1], border_width=1, extend  = extend.right,  border_color = color.new(color.green, 100)))
        else if open < low[1]
            array.unshift(bricks, box.new(left= bar_index - 1, top= low[1], right=bar_index, bottom= open,  border_width=1, extend  = extend.right, border_color = color.new(color.red, 100)))



            
if array.size(bricks) > 0
    if array.size(bricks) == 1
        if high >= box.get_top(array.get(bricks,0)) and low <= box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,0))
            box.delete(array.get(bricks,0))
            array.remove(bricks,0)
        else
            if b == b[1]
                if low[1] <= box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,0)) and high >= box.get_top(array.get(bricks,0)) or high[1] >= box.get_top(array.get(bricks,0)) and low <= box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,0))
                    box.delete(array.get(bricks,0))
                    array.remove(bricks,0)
    else
        t = 0
        for i = 0 to array.size(bricks) - 1
            if high >= box.get_top(array.get(bricks,i - t)) and low <= box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,i - t))
                box.delete(array.get(bricks,i - t))
                array.remove(bricks,i - t)
                t := t + 1
            else
                if i > 0
                    if low[1] <= box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,i - t)) and high >= box.get_top(array.get(bricks,i - t)) or high[1] >= box.get_top(array.get(bricks,i - t)) and low <= box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,i - t))
                        box.delete(array.get(bricks,i - t))
                        array.remove(bricks,i - t)
                        t := t + 1
                        
if array.size(bricks) > 0
    r = 0
    g = 0
    
    for i = 0 to array.size(bricks) - 1
    
///////////////// Conditions
        if high < box.get_top(array.get(bricks,i)) and low > box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,i))
            if high[1] <= box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,i))
                box.set_bottom(array.get(bricks, i), high)
            if low[1] >= box.get_top(array.get(bricks,i))
                box.set_top(array.get(bricks, i), low)
                
                
        else
            if box.get_top(array.get(bricks,i)) > low and low > box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,i))
                box.set_top(array.get(bricks, i), low)
            if box.get_top(array.get(bricks,i)) > high and high > box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,i))
                box.set_bottom(array.get(bricks, i), high)
                
////////////////// Couleur Gap Haussier
        if close >= box.get_top(array.get(bricks,i))
            box.set_bgcolor(array.get(bricks, i), color.new(color.green, 50)) 
            g := g + 20

//////////////// couleurs Gap Baissier 
        else if close <= box.get_bottom(array.get(bricks,i))
            box.set_bgcolor(array.get(bricks, i), color.new(color.red, 50)) 
            r := r + 20


//////////////////////////////// LABELS How to not show label filled gap ??

minimalDeviationTooltip = "Specifies the minimal size of detected gaps, as a percentage of the average high-low range for the last 14 bars."
minimalDeviationInput = nz(input.float(2.0, "Minimal Deviation (%)", tooltip = minimalDeviationTooltip, minval=1, maxval=100) / 100 * ta.sma(high-low, 14))
isGapDown = high < low[1] and low[1] - high >= minimalDeviationInput
isGapUp = open > high[1] and low - high[1] >= minimalDeviationInput

if isGapUp 
    label_bull = label.new(bar_index, na, 'Bull gap: ' + str.tostring((low - high[1] ) / (syminfo.mintick * 100)) , color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar) 
            
if isGapDown
    label_bear = label.new(bar_index-1, na, 'Bull gap: ' + str.tostring((low[1] - high ) / (syminfo.mintick * 100)) , color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

Comment: last 4 lines. also you can hide labels in the indicator style settings

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed I programmed the labels on the last 4 lines but it displays all the gaps including the ones that have been filled. I would like to display only the current gaps (gaps not filled yet) and delete the labels whose gaps have been filled ; but I have no idea of the function I can use for that